# ASP.Net PasswordRecovery class and account enumeration vulnerabillity

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, owasp

Account enumeration means a user can distinguish between valid and invalid account ids because the application responds differently if an account exists vs. when it does not (it either displays a configurable error message or the Success template).

The asp.net PasswordRecovery class handles error and success state internally and there does not seem to be a way to show the same response to the user in these two cases. Or is there? Have you managed to make it always show a neutral message (such as "If you entered a valid account id, you will receive your password recovery email shortly")?

Or in other words, how can I force the control to always display the success message, e.g. from the OnUserLookupError event handler. If this is possible, it is not documented. All the examples [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery?view=netframework-4.8) have this enumeration vulnerability.

Comment: which membership provider are we talking about? curious. i'm using an old one in which i can access and change the code, messages, etc.

Comment: @wazz using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider